# why QPainter is not working in QAbstractItemView::dataChanged?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have used model/view in QT. I have built a custom QAbstractItemView View. As i known, while the data which i set from model have been changed, QAbstractItemView::dataChanged will be called. So i want to write a rect when the data have been changed. The code is as follow. Nothing has been happened while the data have been changed by timer after the view have been built(i don't set initial data in model just set by timer after the view have been built).However, while i set initial data in model is working? Why?

Comment: In View::dataChanged you have memory leak for `img` but seems it's just pseudocode.

Comment: i am not sure if this makes sense at all. this slot is called when you emit that data has changed from for instance an editor widget or the setData function. the view will then use whatever delegate it has to draw this item. you probably want to override the paintEvent in a custom item delegate.

Comment: In my opinion delegate is used for user input. But i just use the timer to update the data, so i just paint the rect in view::datachange

Comment: no it is not, it is used to display it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely reason is that at the point you create a QPixmap from your QImage object, the QPainter's changes haven't been all flushed out to the QPixmap yet.  Try it this way instead:

```
void View::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft,
                  const QModelIndex &bottomRight,
                  const QVector<int> &)
{
   QAbstractItemView::dataChanged(topLeft, bottomRight);

   QImage img(QSize(250, 100), QImage::Format_RGBA8888);

   {
     QPainter painter(&img);
     painter.setPen(Qt::red);
     painter.setBrush(Qt::blue);
     painter.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
   }

   a->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
   [...]
```

By putting the QPainter inside a separate scope, we force the QPainter's destructor to run before setPixmap() is called, thus making sure that it has flushed all of its changes out to the QImage object already.  (alternatively you could call `painter.begin(&img)` before doing your painting calls, and `painter.end(&img)` after you're done, but I think the above approach is less error-prone)

Also note that I changed the QImage to be allocated on the stack rather than using the `new` operator, so that you don't leak a QImage object every time the `dataChanged` method runs.  In C++ you'll want to avoid using the new operator if possible, since every time you use it you have to remember when to call `delete` afterwards, and if you don't, you get a hard-to-diagnose memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure model data is really changed. Simplest way is using `qDebug()` there.

```
#include <QDebug>
...
void View::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft,
              const QModelIndex &bottomRight,
              const QVector<int> &)
{
     qDebug() << "View::dataChanged is called" ;
...
```

Because `QAbstractItemModel::setData` could just return `false` without emitting `dataChanged` signal at all.

If it's non-standard model implemented by you please make sure you implemented `setData` which emits `dataChanged` signal.

Also it's right behaviour for a model to not emit `dataChanged` if editing sets the same value. Here is some typical model behaviour.

```
setData(index, 1); // emitted
setData(index, 1); // nothing changed - dataChanged not emitted
setData(index, 1); // nothing changed - dataChanged not emitted
setData(index, "hello"); // false returned. Should be a number. dataChanged not emitted
setData(index, 2); // emitted
```

Comment: Yes, i checked it! View::dataChanged function has been called every time while timeout();  I don't know why Qpainter not woking

Comment: Could you please share real code you have or minimal example so we could debug and find real problem there.